# Do javafx operations before quit application

Tags: javafx

I would like to open a window with a progress bar when I quit my application while some operations run.

I tried to put my code in the stop method from the Application class but javafx is already down at this moment.

I did the same thing in the first windows like this:

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
    Stage loading = new Stage();
    loading.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    loading.initOwner(primaryStage);
    loading.setScene(new Scene(new Group(JfxUtils.loadFxml(new FXMLLoader(), FxmlFileConstantes.LOADING))));
    loading.show();
});
```

But same thing, it doesn't work.

How can I do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consume the [close request event](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/WindowEvent.html#WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST) in your `onCloseRequest` event handler.

```
event.consume();
```

This will stop the window from closing, which, if the window is the last window in the application, would trigger an application shutdown.

Alternately, you can set [`Platform.setImplicitExit(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#setImplicitExit-boolean-), in which case "the application will continue to run normally even after the last window is closed, until the application calls [`exit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#exit--)".

The JavaFX application lifecycle is defined in the javadoc of the [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) class, which you should probably read to get some more background information.

Comment: ****. Each time, I forget this consume method. Thanks for your answer.